# How to convert Bitmap class used in web service to System.Drawing.Bitmap in C# application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm using asp.net web service  that has a method that take Bitmap parameter. When making service reference in C# winforms application and trying to send bitmap to this web service reference.

My Server Side web-service code is :

```
[WebMethod]
        public void SaveBitmapToServer(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images/bitmap.jpeg"));
        }
```

My Client Side winforms code is :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.MyWSSoapClient ws = new ServiceReference1.MyWSSoapClient();
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("E:\\Images\\1.jpg");
            ws.SaveBitmapToServer(bitmap);
        }
```

This is the error message that appears :
[image: Error Message]

I want to know how to make webservice using `System.Drawing` reference instead of `ServiceRefeerence1.Bitmap` reference Or How to Convert from `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to `ServiceReference1.Bitmap`

Comment: First, do you actually need a `ServiceReference1.Bitmap` custom class? Second, if you do, what's different about it compared to the standard `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class?

Comment: @Mark Benningfield No, i don't . I used System.Drawing.Bitmap in my web service. But visual studio automatically converted it to custom one.

Comment: Most of the time, VS will include the `System.Drawing` namespace for class file templates. Does your Winforms code not reference the `System.Drawing` namespace?

Comment: No it doesn't it just reference custom class named ServiceReference1.Bitmap

Comment: Listen, it looks like this is an ordinary, run-of-the-mill "brainfart". Just delete the custom class definition, and resolve the resulting type reference errors by using the `System.Drawing` namespace.

Comment: Tried that ; the app runs from VS but when trying to connect to WS it gives error "'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 240). ---> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid."

Comment: use a byte array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a byte array instead:

```
[WebMethod]
public void Save(byte[] bytes)
{
    //if for any reason you need to convert it back to image
    var image = (Bitmap)(new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(bytes));
}
```

Comment: However. For any reason if i wanted to use a System class in web service , is there a way to prevent web service from converting it to custom class ?

Comment: When adding web reference, in the advanced dialog of the add service reference, there are some settings which enables you to reuse .NET type. But it wont' work for all types.